# Make a jQuery $.post() to a PHP Controller, and then in the middle of it back to View, and then use $.get() to continue with the Controller

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I am dealing with a View and Controller for a webpage, and I am trying to figure out how this would work:

1. Controller will initially define variables used in view upon page-load.
2. Once a user submits a form, it does an onclick jQuery function, which posts back to the controller.
3. The controller returns back to the View true or false, depending on whether the vote was successfully inserted into the database.
4. The View's jquery function continues, determining what to do next: if it was successful, perform another jQuery function.
5. the next jQuery function performs a $.get back to the controller, which determines the relevant variables to be used in the view.

Right now, mine works in terms of submitting the vote. However, I never see the alert pop-up when i'm running it, which leads me to worry that the set-up I have isn't working the way it should be.

Here is code from my PHP website controller:

```
if(!isset($_POST['poll'])) //UPON PAGE LOAD
{
    //define relevant variables to be put into the view
}
if(isset($_POST['poll'])) //UPON jQuery $.Post() back to controller
{
    if($_POST['poll']=='done')
        $vote = 2;
    if($_POST['poll']=='no')
        $vote = 1;
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $result = vote($user_id, $id, $vote); //inserts vote into Database
    if( !$res )
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true, 'text'=>'success'));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false, 'text'=>'fail'));
    //I want ^this json data to be sent back to the jQuery of my view 

}
if(isset($_GET['newListing']))
{
    //code that would redifine relevant variables to be put into view
}

if(isset($_GET['newListing']) || !isset($_POST['poll']))
{
   //code that does something--both upon page load and when needing to retrieve
   //and define variables to put into view.
}
include('view.php');
```

Here is code from my HTML/jQuery website view:

```
<html> 
<body>   
<form name='poll' id='poll' >
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='done'checked/>Done it.<br/>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='no'/>No.</br>
<button id='submit-vote' onclick="postVote();">Submit</button>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadListing(){
   $.get('controller.php?newListing=yes',function(data){
       if(data.response == 'success'){
           //something}
        else{
           return false;}
   });
 }
 function postVote(){
   $.post('controller.php', { poll: $('input:radio[name=poll]:checked').val(), id: $('input:hidden[name=id]').val()} , function(data){
       if(data.success){
          alert('data.text');
          loadListing();
          return true;}
       else{ 
          alert(data.text);
          return false;}
                    }, 
                    "json");
   }
            </script>
</html>
```

Any help/suggestions appreciated!

**EDIT**:
From my View code:
the HTML:

```
<fieldset id='poll'>
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='yes' checked/>Yes!<br/>
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='done'/>Done it.<br/>
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" name='poll'  value='no'/>No.</br>
 <button id='submit-vote'>Submit</button>
 <INPUT TYPE='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'/>
 </fieldset>
```

the jquery:

```
 jQuery(function($){

                $("#submit-vote").click(
                    function(){ 
                        alert("HELLO");
                        $.post('controller.php', { poll: $('input:radio[name=poll]:checked').val(), id: $('input:hidden[name=id]').val()} , 
                        function(data)
                        {
                            alert("THIS FUNCTION WORKS");

                        }, "json"); 
                    }
                );
            });
```

The controller is pretty much the same. When I click on the submit button now, the `alert("HELLO");` is executed, and according to the Firefox's Firebug the `$.post()` does take place. However, the `alert("THIS FUNCTION WORKS");` does NOT get executed. 
I need help figuring out why that may be....

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example page that we can look at and see the code in action?

Comment: I guess not. Chances are that if your `alert()` isn't working then your javascript isn't compiling since you haven't written it properly (see @maxedison's answer).

Comment: thanks! I have edited my question to be more specific now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `include('view.php');` should ONLY to be put into the `if(!isset($_POST['poll'])) //UPON PAGE LOAD`code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that json_encode creates a string. In your Javascript, however, you're trying to access it as if it's an object (data.success). You'd need to first use window.JSON.parse() to turn it into an object:

```
var dataObj = window.JSON.parse(data);
```

After doing that, you should be able to access dataObj.success.

To be honest though, I'm not sure why you're making it that complicated. Why not just return a simple string, such as "success" or "failure"? Then you don't need to encode the object in php or decode it in JavaScript. You'd simply do:

**PHP**

```
if( !$res )
        echo 'success';
else
        echo 'failure';
```

**JavaScript**

```
if(data === 'success'){
    //do your stuff
}else{ 
    //do other stuff
}
```

**Edit in response to OP's first comment on this answer**
Your JavaScript will regain control once the PHP script ends. In the code you posted, you include a view.php file at the end of the PHP script. I don't know what's inside view.php, and it's quite possible that including this file will cause your JS alert() to still not fire even if you make the changes I described above. That's because if there is any output (i.e. echo, print, etc.) that runs in the view.php file, that will get appended to the string created by json_encode. The result will be a string that can not be parsed by window.JSON.parse().

If you want the script to end after echoing "success" or "failure" (or your json_encoded version), simply put `return;` after the echo statement:

```
if( !$res ){
    echo 'success';
else
    echo 'failure';
}
return;
```

Comment: My question was more about how to get it to go back to the jquery after the success/failure has been defined in the controller.

Comment: thank you, that helps with my understanding of it. I am running into a specific problem now--please see my Edited question. Again, many thanks.

Comment: What does Firebug tell you about the response? Is it 200 OK, 404 Page Not Found, 500 Internal Server error, etc? You should be able to find this by inspecting the response headers.

Comment: 200 OK, and I know that the post was successful also because it shows `{"response":"success"}` in the HTML, according to firebug.

Comment: i think i figured out a problem (or at least a way to fix it): i was using jquery to post to the same controller that controls the entire page, so once I moved the specific code to a different file to echo out the success or failure response so that the jquery function only calls that specific file, it worked!

Comment: and now i have figured out a way to do it without putting it into a separate file: see my answer below :)